# SharedPrefernces на несколько активити

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Использую `SharedPreference` для настроек приложения, есть единственное но, как сделать чтобы `SharedPrefernce` можно было вызвать из любого активити?

Я имею виду, что есть у меня `Settings_activity`, вот как `SharedPreference` созданный в нем использовать для других активити, чтобы передавался ключ и значение, вообще как `intent.putExtra`

---

**Необходимо сначала создать связку ключей:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.apply();
```

**А после из другого активити вызвать:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String s = sharedPref.getString("key");
```

Answer (score 2):

- используете [getPreferences(int mode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getPreferences(int)), если работаете с данными для текущего `Activity` и не хотите выдумывать имя файла.
- используете [getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)), если сохраняете, например, данные - общие для нескольких `Activity` и сами выбираете имя файла для сохранения.

[источник](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/73-urok-33-hranenie-dannyh-preferences.html)

Comment: я это читал, интересует именно как из другого активить получить доступ

Comment: @k1ceargy, методом  `getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)` с тем же именем, что и в первой активности.

Answer (score 1):

Объявить переменные в обеих активити:

```
    public SharedPreferences apppref;
    public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "apppref";
```

в первой Activity:

```
    apppref = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = apppref.edit();
    editor.putString("mAppIUD", "123456789-987654321");
    editor.apply();
```

во второй Activity:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String s = sharedPref.getString("mAppIUD", "unknown");
    Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "mysettings";// это будет именем файла настроек
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_NAME = "Nickname"; // имя кота
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_AGE = "Age"; // возраст кота
SharedPreferences mSettings;
```

Внутри какого-то метода

```
mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

и работайте с этим файлом. у него имя есть, по имени он вызовется откуда угодно, в пределах приложения точно. если выберете более публичный модификатор, то и не только внутри приложения его можно будет читать. Не хотите по имени - пользуйтесь DefaultSharedPreferences. Все есть в сети, оттуда и пример.

Answer (score 0):

Я уже когда то отвечал на этот вопрос , скопирую ответ сюда. Не п найте строго. Сижу с телефона не знаю как отправить ссылку

Ели в приложении есть `PreferenceActivity` или фрагмент, то там устанавливается значение по умолчанию для каких то параметров, это можно сделать программно, а можно по простому через `XML`. Вот , меню, например, для настройки текста в активности, 
а `key` это ключ по которому можно достучаться до настройки.

```
menu.xml:
 <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="1"
        android:entries="@array/entry_values"
        android:entryValues="@array/entries"
        android:key="@string/list_preference_1"
        android:summary="%s"
        android:title="Размер шрифта" />
```

где:

```
<!-- ВЫБОР ШРИФТА -->
<string-array name="entries">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="entry_values">
    <item>Мелкий</item>
    <item>Средний</item>
    <item>Крупный</item>
</string-array>
```

в самом фрагменте настроек `PreferenceFragment` ему можно повесить слушатель в методе `onSharedPreferenceChanged`, например снэкбар для уведомления о том, что настройка изменена:

```
 if (key.equals(getString(R.string.list_preference_1))) {
        snackbar = Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Размер шрифта изменен", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = snackBarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.white));
        snackbar.show();
    }
```

А вот так можно вызвать настройку в активности или там где она нужна и привязать к ней нужные текстВью:

```
    private static final int TEXT_SIZE_SMALL = 14, TEXT_SIZE_MID = 18,TEXT_SIZE_LARGE = 22 ;

     private void getSetting() {
        String txt_view_size = preferences.getString(getString(R.string.list_preference_1), "1");
//это значение по умолчанию

if (txt_view_size.contains("2")) {
                txt_view.setTextSize(TEXT_SIZE_MID);
            } else if (txt_view_size.contains("3")) {
                txt_view.setTextSize(TEXT_SIZE_LARGE);
            } else {
                txt_view.setTextSize(TEXT_SIZE_SMALL);
            }
        }
```

так вы получите настройку по умолчанию и возможность менять её через меню настроек

Допрлню если нужно просто сохранять вызывать

```
Записать пару ключ-значение:

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE); SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit(); editor.putString("key", "value"); editor.commit();

Прочитать значение ключа:

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE); String s = sharedPref.getString("key");
```